# How to implement automatic timestamps for record changes (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, timestamp

I am used to using "changed_at" fields in my MySQL database that Ruby on Rails automatically updates when changing a record.

Now I am using ASP.NET MVC with SQL Server 2008 and I am wondering, how would I proceed to get the same functionality. Does SQL Server have an option for auto updating a field when updating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "timestamp" data type gives you a binary value that automatically gets updated every time your field changes, but it won't give you a nice date/time value.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a trigger or just update it in an sp that does the update.

Comment: you'll have to update the row an extra time if you want a trigger to do it because you can't update INSERTED.  Just set the value when you update the other columns and be done with it.

Comment: I would agree with updating the field when you are updating the rest of the record, but a trigger can be used to accomplish the "auto" update of the field.

Answer (score 1):

do this...

```
UPDATE YourTable
    SET Column1=@...
        ,@Column2=@....
        ,@Column3=@...
        ,changed_at=GETDATE()
    WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **rowversion** which has the same effect but is supported going forward

Reference - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx